# Link's clickable area moves when scrolling on ASUS Transformer tablet

Tags: css, html, tablet

I have a really frustating problem im stuck with, I googled around a lot, maybe im searching for wrong phrases, but cant find a solution.

So i have table inside a div (a box), which is scrollable in the inside and the parent is also scrollable. The layout works fine with other tablets, but on ASUS Transformer i have the following problem:

If i scroll the body of the document and try to click on the link in the table (the table cells contain forms with hidden fields and a link) the clickable area moves. It seems like scrolling also moves the links, but the link labels, the hidden fields and the parent div stays in the correct position. It is only visibile due to the wrong position of the link outlines (and of course, that the links dont work if i click them after scrolling).

I was thinking about some weird margin collapse effect, but the elements inside are cleared, and overflow:auto is added to the parent. Maybe its some ASUS related bug?

The content is HTML5.

This is the part which fills the table with the links. WebView is used for displaying the content.

```
<div class="table_content_back" >
                        <div class="scrollable_content" >
                            <!-- BLOCK CONTENT STARTS HERE -->
                            <div class="table_content">
                                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="table" >

                                    <tr id="t_h">
                                        <th class="ta_left t_header"><%= message("siteName")%></th>
                                    </tr>

                                    <i:foreach var="ListItem" index="i" list="${sites}">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="ta_left" id="site_list">
                                                <form name="Site-${i}" >
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="actionid" value="SharePoint/Flow" />
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="flow" value="sitebrowser" /> 
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="sitename" value="${ListItem.title}" />
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="siteurl" value="${ListItem.url}" />
                                                    <a href="javascript:invitoSubmit('Site-${i}');">${ListItem.title}</a>
                                                </form>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </i:foreach>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I cant help you but maybe you should add some code showing the problem and tell us what browser you use for testing on your Transformer (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Dolphin, Stock Android etc.)

Comment: Ok, thx, added some more information, maybe it helps.